# Validation Messages not displaying with Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5.6 SPA, Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am getting a 422 response from the server when expected and the correct server-side messages appear in the console but I cant seem to get these messages to display in my view. Any ideas?

I am using Laravel 5.6 with Vue.js 2 and Axios and following the lessons for Vus.js on laracasts (great lessons).

```
    <template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Create Person</h1>
        </div>
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" action="POST">
            <div>
                <label for="fname" class="col-md-3 control-label ">First Name:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" name="fname" v-model='fname' id="fname" autocomplete='off'>
                    <span v-text="errors.get('fname')"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lname" class="col-md-3 control-label ">Last Name:</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" name="lname" v-model='lname' id="lname" autocomplete='off'>
                    <span v-text="errors.get('lname')"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-trans-green square pull-right card-1">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
  </template>

<script>

    class Errors {
        constructor(){
            this.errors = {};
        }
        get(field){
            if (this.errors[field]){
                return this.errors[field][0];
            }
        }
        record(errors){
            this.errors = errors;
        }
    }

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                fname:'',
                lname:'',
                errors: new Errors()
            }
        },
        methods: {
          onSubmit(){
              axios.post('/customers', this.$data)
                      .then(response =>  alert('Success'))
                      .catch(error => 
  this.errors.record(error.response.data));
          }
        }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Why you use a class??There is a simple way to do it.

Comment: Show result of: `console.log(error.response.data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.5 (I think) the JSON response for validation errors changed from being just an object of errors to an object containing errors and a single message. So to access the error messages in the response you will actually need to do:

```
this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors)
```

I would suggest, if you don't have it already, to get [Vue Devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#installation) the addon/extension to help you debug your code and just see what's going on in general.

Finally, just an FYI, Spatie made a package for this a while back (based on Jeff's lesson). You could use it as a point of reference if you're just going through the lessons and want to build it yourself.

[Spatie - Form Backend Validation](https://github.com/spatie/form-backend-validation)

Comment: That did it! I have Dev Tools and its been useful but when I started making an SPA the only information Devtools shows is a list of <router-link> tags and nothing more. Maybe I should ask a separate question to get that sorted out. Thanks Ross!